# Transferring Tokens

Tags: eosio.token, transfer

I have a few accounts I would like to combine. How would it best be done? Everytime I try to transfer them, I get a DOS command line that I have no clue what to do with.

Comment: If you are getting an error of some kind you need to post it here otherwise we cannot really help.

Comment: Also your CLI commands or code would help...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.